# Maximum request length exceeded despite config values being set

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, file-upload, web-config, blobstorage, maxrequestlength

I am having some issues when uploaded files of greater than 4MB to blob storage using an MVC application that I am working on. I have added the necessary code in the web.config as shown below:

**Within system.web**

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" executionTimeout="3600" />
```

**Within system.webserver**

```
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

I have rebuilt my web project and my azure project but I am still getting the maximum request length exceeded error. Any ideas what might be causing this? Stack trace is as follows:

**[HttpException (0x80004005): Maximum request length exceeded.]
   System.Web.HttpRequest.GetEntireRawContent() +12603644
   System.Web.HttpRequest.GetMultipartContent() +221
   System.Web.HttpRequest.FillInFormCollection() +357
   System.Web.HttpRequest.EnsureForm() +110
   System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Form() +16
   System.IdentityModel.Services.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.IsSignInResponse(HttpRequestBase request) +32
   System.IdentityModel.Services.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.CanReadSignInResponse(HttpRequestBase request, Boolean onPage) +129
   System.IdentityModel.Services.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.OnAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs args) +152
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +80
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +165**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maximum request length exceeded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853767/maximum-request-length-exceeded)

Comment: Are you find a solution ?

Comment: i tried your code and it works for me.

Comment: There is a web.config file in Views folder. You might have changed that mistakenly instead of changing Web.Config in root path of the project

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem, the problem was silly

In my web.config there were already a httpRuntime tag with targetFramework attribute specified.

I created a second httpRuntime tag instead of add maxRequestLength in the already present httpRuntime tag. So my value was ignored.